# How can I draw a layout when a task is running in Kotlin

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, asynchronous, mobile

I explain the situation, I made an algo that displays the shortest path through all the points, this algo takes a little time to run that's why I wanted to set up a progress bar to induce the user of the application has not frozen but is performing a calculation, To do this I simply created a layout with a progress bar but when I execute the code nothing is displayed (the layout) but the result of my algo is displayed, is there a command to display it?

progress_bar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText"
    android:id="@+id/download_root"
    android:background="@color/background_main"
   tools:context=".ui.farm.DaturaFragment">


   <com.mikhaellopez.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/route_progress"
       android:layout_width="@dimen/sync_central_icon_height"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/sync_central_icon_height"
       app:cpb_background_progressbar_color="@color/blue_dark"
       app:cpb_background_progressbar_width="14dp"
       app:cpb_indeterminate_mode="true"
       app:cpb_progress="0"
       app:cpb_progress_direction="to_right"
       app:cpb_progress_max="100"
       app:cpb_progressbar_color="@color/green"
       app:cpb_progressbar_width="7dp"
       app:cpb_round_border="true"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.405"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />


   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/download_subtitle"
       android:layout_width="500dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@color/background_main"
       android:text="Calculation of the current purification route?"
       android:textAlignment="center"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       android:textFontWeight="600"
       android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:visibility="gone"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.57"
       tools:visibility="visible" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

on my mainActivity.xml:

```
<include
            android:id="@+id/dialogue_route"
            layout="@layout/route_datura_dialog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
```

```
 datura_path_epuration.setOnClickListener {
            if (epurationStateButton == 0) {
                if (pointsOnThefield != null && !mapViewHelper.getEpurationFinished(pointsOnThefield!!)) {
                    if (buttonState == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Please enable geolocation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    } else {

                        displayDialogueRoute()

                        mapViewHelper.displayEpurationPath(pointsOnThefield!!)

                        removeDialogueRoute()

                    }
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(context, "All daturas have been purified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                epurationStateButton = 1
            }else {
                mapViewHelper.deletePolyLine()
                epurationStateButton = 0
            }
        }
```

```
private fun displayDialogueRoute(){
        dialogue_route.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        datura_location_cta.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        datura_path_epuration.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        detail_close.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        datura_non_eputration_cta.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        datura_eputration_cta.visibility= View.INVISIBLE
    }
    private fun removeDialogueRoute(){
        dialogue_route.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        datura_location_cta.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        datura_path_epuration.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        detail_close.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you use the default ProgressBar unless there is a reason for you not to?

Comment: I use this circular progress bar because it allows me to better style my bar I tried with the default progress bar but it did not change anything

Comment: And the width and height is proper? Just try with `wrap_content` once and make sure you are handling the visibility of it properly.

Comment: I think that it does not come from the xml file because when I put in comment the function that calls my algo "mapViewHelper.displayEpurationPath(pointsOnThefield!!) "and "removeDialogueRoute()" the progress bar is visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there are threading issues. The long-running task could be blocking the UI during its calculations.

How about trying the exhaustive algorithm on the background and updating the UI (progressbar in this case) when the calculation is complete from the background?

You can use the popular Kotlin-Coroutine to achieve this.

You can copy-paste try it:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { 
           //Main UI Thread
           withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
           //Background Thread
           //Perform long-running task here
           }
           //Task finished, Update Progress Bar here
        }
```

Comment: thank you very much it was the solution obviously